# Different variable values assigned conditionally

Tags: javascript

I have a result coming from an AJAX call which I would like to test: in case it's equals to 'nobody' then I want a variable `people` assigned to 'No people', otherwise I want to output whatever I get.

This is my code:

```
const result = JSON.parse(oReq.responseText);
for (var dinner of result) {
    if (dinner.diners.name != 'nobody')) {
    const res = dinner.diners.name.map(diner => {
    return obj.person
    })
    let people = res.join('<br/>* ')
    }
    [...]
    let output = dinner.diners.name == 'nobody' ? 'No-one' : people
```

Why am I always getting `people is not defined`, even when `dinner.diners.name == 'nobody'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's time to get a better JS development environment set up! A linter should be able to detect the fact that the variable `people` does not exist in the scope you're trying to access it in.

The assignment keywords `let` and `const` are block scoped (whatever is wrapped in curly braces). That means that the variable is only available within the block and blocks within it. To fix this, declare `people` in the right scope: outside of the `for..of` loop.

```js
const result = JSON.parse(oReq.responseText);
let people
for (var dinner of result) {
    if (dinner.diners.name != 'nobody')) {
        const res = dinner.diners.name.map(diner => {
            return obj.person
        })
        people = res.join('<br/>* ')
    }
}
let output = dinner.diners.name == 'nobody' ? 'No-one' : people
```

Notice that I took out the `let` assignment of `people` inside the loop. If you assign it there, then `people` in the loop is different from the `people` above the loop